In "Man of the West", who plays Dock Tobin's accomplice in the train?
In the movie Man of the West the attack of the train involves four men of Dock Tobin's (Lee J. Cobb) gang. Three wait for the train hidden under a small bridge,  Coaley (Jack Lord), Trout (Royal Dano) and Ponch (Robert J. Wilke). But there is a fourth accomplice in the train, who is hit by a bullet in the back when fleeing, and is later killed by Coaley - a mercy killing to shorten his suffering since he can't be treated for his wound.
But I could not find his name on IMDB. They do give a few "Train Passengers" but none of them look like the one who is seen shooting on the guard (and missing) and jumping on the horse of one of the other three when the attack fails, just before being hit in the back.
I don't remember the name they call him before Coaley kills him.
So can anyone tell me what is the name of the character, and who is the actor ?

The part of Alcutt was played by an uncredited Jack Williams, according to IMDB and the AFI.
Per Wikipedia;

Link tries to intervene and is knocked unconscious. The train departs, with Alcutt riding off with Link's bag containing Good Hope's money. Alcutt is wounded as he and the three other robbers flee.

And from the DVD subtitles

That's Alcutt. He's got a hole in his back. He's gonna die. He wasn't much good anyway.


Thanks. I did not identify the name "Alcutt" in the scene where Coaley kills him. My hearing is not particularly good...  No DVD, I watched it on the TV (in French !!!)
